# .rptproj.user file always checked out by TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, tfs, azure-devops

I have a solution in TFS which has reporting services projects in it.  For some reason whenever I get latest it gets the code and checks out the solution.  Then is says that the .rptproj.user file has had changes made to it and thus the solution is checked out.

I checked the source code on TFS and there is no .rptproj.user file, so I don't know why this is happening.

Perhaps it has something to do with the build profile or perhaps because I don't have some business intelligence tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a Visual Studio solution (.sln) holds a reference to all the projects under it's umbrella. So if you make a change to a project, its parent solution file will be modified and need to be checked out as well.

Try opening a .sln with Notepad++ (or your favorite text editor) and you will see what I mean.